# MongoDB- Is it possible not to use cache in order to test the speed of the query?

Tags: mongodb, caching, groovy

I am using **groovy language** to implement MongoDB's queries. I want to test the speed of my query. But because of the cache, I am not able to predict it. I searched on google but I was not able to make it.

**Problem:** Is there any query that force MongoDB not to use the cache. I tried db.collection.getPlanCache().clear() in groovy language but it is not helping. Is there any way to handle it using groovy language?

Answer (score 0):

try this `db.collection.find(<query>).close()`

Comment: I am using aggregation query which includes pipeline using Groovy language. How can I use the above query? Can you elaborate a little bit in groovy language?

Comment: Could you explain how this triggers MongoDB to avoid cache.

Comment: @Lex I used a close() method. Still, I am not able to trigger MongoDB to avoid cache. I am also looking for a query or command to allow MongoDB not to use the cache (Means directly reads from the Disk) so that I can get the Read.

Answer (score 0):

Your groovy code should be like this.

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate(<pipeline>).close()
```

The call to `.close()` should free the resources as suggested here - [.close()](https://vertx.io/docs/groovydoc/io/vertx/groovy/ext/mongo/MongoClient.html#close())

Comment: Thanks, But I am reading data from MongoDB using aggregation. But I am getting Read: 0 KB/s. Even though the close() method instructs the server to close a cursor and free the associated server resources. Can you suggest how can I get this "Read"?

Comment: @Ankit Can you please share the screenshot of the output you are getting?

Comment: I am getting the correct output. But I am looking for a query or command to allow MongoDB not to use the cache (Means directly reads from the Disk) so that I can get the Read percentage in Task manager.